# TFS 2010 version control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

We want to start using the TFS version control on our project. I read the tutorial and noticed that TFS creates tables in the sql db. My questions are:

1. What are these tables for?
2. Where is the vs solution actually stored?
3. How can I use more then one instance of our solution from another computer (another developer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. TFS stores pretty much all its data in few SQL database: source control, work items, build definitions, build results etc.
2. In the SQL database for the Team Project Collection, specifics about which tables etc should not matter to you.  Users setup a workspace which maps the directory structure in source control to a place on their local disk.
3. I'm not sure what you're asking here, can you try clarify your question?

Comment: so my solution is being stored in my local hard disk? not at MS cloud?

Comment: @mashtagidi The master copy of the solution and the history are kept on the server in the database, in order to edit you "get" the code from TFS to your local machine, then you "check out" the code and edit it. You then "check in" the code to publish is back to the TFS server. Once the code is checked in you (or another developer) can "get" to another machine.

Comment: @mashtagidi: you ask about the "cloud". There is a TFS _Service_ that is hosted in the cloud, and there is a TFS _Server_ that you can host on your own premises.

Comment: @John Saunders do you mean I have to choose between the two?

Comment: @mashtagidi: They are the same thing, more or less. You just have to decide where you want your TFS server to live. In your data center or in Microsoft's data center.